# How to register PMI handler?

Tags: x86, kernel, interrupt, cpu-registers, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to register an interrupt handler for the performance monitoring interrupt (PMI).

I was hoping I could just find the IRQ line number by looking in /proc/interrupts `grep PMI /proc/interrupts` but when I try to register that irq using `register_irq`, the system hangs.

I've also been reading about APIC in the Intel documentation, but it's not clear to me how to actually use it. There is an APIC register for the performance monitoring counter's local vector table (which is presumably related to the PMI), which can be read and written to, but I'm not sure if I can use that to define the entrypoint for my custom PMI handler.

What is the relationship between the Local Vector Table in the APIC, the interrupt request line, and the value shown in /proc/interrupts?

I should also mention I'm on a 2.6 kernel (HPC system, no chance to update), sandybridge.

Comment: Try to ask on forum.osdev.org .

Comment: Thank you, FWIW it is posted here: http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27040

Comment: Note that it's more osdev forum, so you may not get answers on OS-specific or platform-specific questions.